# Change inherited height

Tags: css

I got something like:

```
.parent {
  height: 400px
}

.child {
  height: inherit;
}
```

and I need to change an inherited height by pixels -> 
something like this

```css
.child {
  height: inherit - 10px
}
```

so `child height` will be `390px` in our case.
Problem is that inherited height is an object.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can use calc, people were doing things like this long before calc:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red; 
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100px;
  position: relative; 
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid blue; 
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 10px; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I cant use calc, because it has some crashes in phone enviroment. The old way worked for me :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```css
.child {
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

Comment: Just note that it isn't entirely cross-browser compatible.

Comment: @Crowes Which browsers are not supported?

Comment: @Crowes Only browser that doesn't support it is IE 9 and lower does anybody support that still? MS doesn't support it anymore

Comment: Entirely is a keyword here.

Comment: Also not supported in Netscape Navigator.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I cant use calc, because it has some crashes in phone environment.